# OpenVPN- Transfering configuration to client device: Can't resolve hostname

Tags: dns, openvpn, sftp

I was installing OpenVPN in Ubuntu 16.04 and and I needed to transfer the configuration to the client device using this command:

```
sftp sammy@openvpn_server_ip:client-configs/files/client1.ovpn ~/
```

I got an error saying:

```
could not resolve hostname openvpn_server_ip: name or service not found
```

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: Are you able to ping the server ip from the other machine?

Comment: Yes I was able to ping from other machines

Comment: Can you try executing the command again with `-vvv` appended, e.g., `sftp -vvv ...`?

Comment: I have appended the -vvv in the command, still giving me "could not resolve hostname openvpn_server_ip"

Comment: Apologies for not communicating effectively. You were supposed to update your post with the output from running the command with the verbose flag enabled to provided more information for debugging.